# why Jasmine is not returning fake data?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a component that calls a service class to do some operation. The service class uses httpClient to call an eternal api. I am trying to test the component as follows :

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [SomeService],
    }).compileComponents();
    service = TestBed.get(SomeService);
  }));

 fit('should', async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const fakeHttpPromise = {
      success: function () { }
    };
    spyOn(service, 'save').and.callFake(function () {
      return fakeHttpPromise;
    });

    const textbox1 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[formControlName=control1]'));
    textbox1.nativeElement.value = 'value';

    const textbox2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[formControlName=constrol2]'));
    textbox2.nativeElement.value = 'value';

    // here i Create model object using textbox1 and textbox2 value
    // This should not call actual service 
    component.Save(model);
    fixture.detectChanges();



    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(service.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

This is the components Save click :

```
Save(model: any) {
      this.Service.save(model)
        .then((res) => {
        }
  }
```

Question: why the actual service is called when the spy is returning fake promise? The actual service uses httpclient and I don't want to actually call it but just return a fake promise.

Comment: can you add the component code also?

Comment: delete fixture.detectChanges here :  fit('should', async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

Comment: deleting fixture.dectectChanges() did not help. Any ideas ? component Save click is already provided . Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I solved this problem :

1) Changed my Save click to call the service from local method in component:

```
Save(model: any) {
      this.btnsave(model).then((res) => {
        }
  }

btnsave(model){
 return this.Service.save(model);
}
```

2) Change the test as:

```
   fit('should', async () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const fakeHttpPromise = Promise.resolve();
// spy on components method
        spyOn(component, 'btnsave').and.returnvalue(fakeHttpPromise);

        const textbox1 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[formControlName=control1]'));
        textbox1.nativeElement.value = 'value';

        const textbox2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[formControlName=constrol2]'));
        textbox2.nativeElement.value = 'value';

        // here i Create model object using textbox1 and textbox2 value
        // This should not call actual service 
        component.Save(model);
        fixture.detectChanges();



        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
          fixture.detectChanges();
// check on component method     
          expect(component.btnsave).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
      });
```